Get random string element
I'm trying to create a string of 116 random characters, I'm terrible at understanding batch files but I managed to create a random number rand from 0 to 15 to get an element from hex_chars=0123456789ABCDEF
But when I try to get and output an element from a string of characters I constantly encounter problems.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Define the length of the random hex string
set "hex_length=116"

REM Initialize the hex characters
set "hex_chars=0123456789ABCDEF"

REM Variable to store the random hex string
set "random_hex="

REM Loop until the required length is reached
for /L %%i in (1,1,%hex_length%) do (
    REM Generate a random number between 0 and 15
    set /a "rand=((%random% * %random% + %random% %% 281 * %%i) + %time:~-2%) %% 16"
    echo !rand!

    REM Returns 0 every time
    echo !hex_chars:~%rand%,1! 

    REM Returns 0123456789ABCDEFrand every time
    echo !hex_chars:~!rand!,1! 

    REM Get the hex character from hex_chars based on the random number
    set random_hex=%random_hex%!hex_chars:~%rand%,1!
)

REM Output the random hex string
echo Random Hex (116 chars): !random_hex!

endlocal
pause

I thought to get the hex_string element via for but I didn't figure out how to do it correctly
I tried changing the % and ! and ^ symbols in !hex_chars:~!rand!,1!

You might consider implementing this in Python, Ruby, or some other scripting language where it’s pretty trivial, then calling the script from your batch file. In Ruby: ruby -e 'puts Array.new(116) { rand(16).to_s(16) }.join'

set random_hex=!random_hex!%hex_chars:~!rand!,1%

@elzooilogico: That don't works because the %hex_chars:...,1% part would be expanded just once in the loop. The right way would be call set random_hex=!random_hex!%%hex_chars:~!rand!,1%% but the FOR method is better. See my answer below...

Don't worry. The management of variables is one of the most confusing points in Batch files, specially the Delayed Expansion feature. The two key points to remember are these:

You can not use %standard% expansion inside a command when the value of the variable changes in the same command, like inside a FOR loop; you must use !delayed! expansion instead. There are a lot of questions/answers in this site about this point; I suggest you to read this answer or this one.

The second point is that variable expansions can NOT be nested using the same expansion char (% or !); you can only place a %normal% expansion inside a !delayed! one. For example: echo !hex_chars:~!rand!,1! is wrong. You must use a "trick" to avoid such nesting as explained here or here.


If we apply the first point to your code, your %random% and %time:~-2% expansions must be !random! and !time:~-2! if you want they change in every iteration. And applying the second point, the final working code is this:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Define the length of the random hex string
set "hex_length=116"

REM Initialize the hex characters
set "hex_chars=0123456789ABCDEF"

REM Variable to store the random hex string
set "random_hex="

REM Loop until the required length is reached
for /L %%i in (1,1,%hex_length%) do (

    REM Generate a random number between 0 and 15
    set /a "rand=((!random! * !random! + !random! %% 281 * %%i) + !time:~-2!) %% 16"
    rem echo !rand!

    REM Get the hex character from hex_chars based on the random number
    for %%r in (!rand!) do set "random_hex=!random_hex!!hex_chars:~%%r,1!
)

REM Output the random hex string
echo Random Hex (116 chars): %random_hex%

endlocal
pause


You could opt to get the assistance of PowerShell in your batch file for this type of task too.
Display string:
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(1..116 | %%{'{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16)}) -Join ''"
@Pause

String to file:
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Set-Content -Path '.\HexChars.txt' -Value ((1..116 | %%{'{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16)}) -Join '')"

String to variable:
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(1..116 | %%{'{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16)}) -Join ''"') Do @Set "HexStr=%%G"
@Set HexStr
@Pause

